# Searching in a multidimensional array in twig

Tags: php, html, twig

I have a template with multiple lists created from one array.

PHP:

```
$array = [
    ['type' => 'A', 'name' => 'string 1'],
    ['type' => 'B', 'name' => 'string 2'],
    ['type' => 'A', 'name' => 'string 3'],
    ['type' => 'B', 'name' => 'string 4']
];
```

HTML:

```
<h4>A</h4>
<ul>
    {% for value in array %}
        {% if value.type == 'A' %}
            {{ value.name }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
<h4>B</h4>
<ul>
    {% for value in array %}
        {% if value.type == 'B' %}
            {{ value.name }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But I don't want to display the `<h4>` and `<ul>` when a type cannot be found.
How can I do that?

Comment: That is possible, but it will require a lot of logic in the template. It would be much easier and make more sense to split the array into two arrays in the controller.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Proper solution: "Refactor" your array in the controller, so that the "type" is used as a key, like this:

```
$arrayByType = [
    [ 'A' => [
        ['type' => 'A', 'name' => 'string 1'],
        ['type' => 'A', 'name' => 'string 3']
    ],
    [ 'B' => [
        ['type' => 'B', 'name' => 'string 2'],
        ['type' => 'B', 'name' => 'string 4']
    ],
];
```

This can be done like this:

```
$arrayByType = array();
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $arrayByType[$item['type']][] = $item;
}
```

And in the template you then just need to:

```
{% if arrayByType["A"] is not empty %}
    <h4>A</h4>
    <ul>
        {% for value in arrayByType["A"] %}
            <li>{{ value.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>    
{% endif %}
```

---

Bad solution (inside the template):

```
{% set displayA = false %}
{% for item in array if item.type == 'A' %}
    {% set displayA = true %}
    {# There is no "break" in twig, so that makes this extremely suboptimal #}
{% endfor %}
{% if displayA %}
    <h4>A</h4>
    <ul>
        {% for item in array if item.type == 'A' %}
            <li>{{ value.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>    
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Knew this was possible, wanted a nicer option.. though I couldn't find it I implemented it like this. Thanks anyway, will accept your answer

Comment: A nicer of which solution? The first solution is the nicer one than the second solution. And I can't think of a nicer solution than the first - except have your data modeled "correctly" in the first place making the "refactoring" unnecessary.

Comment: I hoped for something like array_filter from php, like:
$array = array_filter($array, function($val) {
    return $val == 'A'
});

and then loop over that array, both in twig.

Comment: TWIG only has a very simple scripting language, because logic doesn't belong in the template (have a look at [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/) which doesn't have hardly any logic at all). You could howver write such a filter function yourself by writing an extension for Twig: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html

Answer (score 0):

Here will only print the type when type exists. [Twig for loop condition](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#adding-a-condition)

```
{% for item in array if item.type == 'A' %}
    {% if loop.first %}<h4>A</h4>{% endif %}
    {{ item.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

As suggested @RoToRa, its much easier to do it in controller and make more sense or maybe perhaps pass the work the db to handle. Its will depend of the design where is better off to have the data to be separated. Also keep in mind that the view is suppose to display, keep the logical code in controller.

Hope this help

Comment: It won't work like that. You would need to put the `<ul>` around that loop, leading to the `<h4>` being inside the `<ul>`.

Comment: it is not working. Error: `Error! Unexpected token "name" of value "if" ("end of statement block" expected).`

Answer (score -1):

You can use like below:

```
{% for value in array %}
{% if value.type !='' %}
<h4>{{ value.type }}</h4>
<ul>      
              {{ value.name }}
       </ul>
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: that will loop the `<h4>`